# How to increase timeout for an Azure Service Fabric Actor?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I found in our error logs that our Azure Service Fabric stateless service encountered a `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.DuplicateMessageException` while trying to invoke a method on an Actor proxy after a period of time. The actor can take a while to run. The full message of the exception was:

> Actor Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorConcurrencyLock  got
>   same request more than once. This might happen for a request which
>   takes more processing time than configured OperationTimeout on
>   Client side as client retries on TimeoutException.

I do not see anywhere that I can configure this value. I see a reference to it in [the documentation for the `FabricTransportSettings` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.fabrictransport.common.fabrictransportsettings.aspx) but I can't tell where that type is being used.

Since our actor method is expected to take a while to run (often minutes), if this error is indeed related to a timeout, how do I increase the OperationTimeout?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider changing how the actor works in that you initialize and "seed" the actor with the needed parameters. Then fire a timer to execute the long running work. Then re-query the actor until the work is complete and retrieve result.

We have a couple long running workloads using actors in our system that we setup to work this way

Comment: I think that's a good suggestion from an architecture perspective and I'll definitely try it out. Unfortunately though it doesn't really answer the question so I can't mark it as an answer. Is it possible to increase the timeout, and if so, how?

Comment: Fair enough, I do remember reading something at one point that said for alterations to the FabricTransportSettings, you have to make the changes on both ends of the wire (the requester, and on the listener on the receiving end)

Comment: I recently ran into this issue as well.  I took the advice of not increasing the timeout but instead fired off an actor and set a timer for the long running task and then used actor based events that can be subscribed from the calling service to receive notifications for when work is complete.  You can read more about actor events @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-events.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Timeout value at the assembly level.

```
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport;
[assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(MaxMessageSize = int.MaxValue,OperationTimeoutInSeconds =2000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider putting the section below into your Settings.xml file:

```
<Section Name="TransportSettings">
    <Parameter Name="MaxMessageSize" Value="1073741824" />
    <Parameter Name="OperationTimeoutInSeconds" Value="6000" />
</Section>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-fabrictransportsettings